# Xamarin Form, iOS Supporting IPv6-only Networks

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, ipv6

I've just submitted my app to Appstore and got this error:

> At WWDC 2015 we announced the transition to IPv6-only network services
>   in iOS 9. Starting June 1, 2016 all apps submitted to the App Store
>   must support IPv6-only networking. Most apps will not require any
>   changes because IPv6 is already supported by NSURLSession and
>   CFNetwork APIs.
>
> If your app uses IPv4-specific APIs or hard-coded IP addresses, you
>   will need to make some changes. Learn how to ensure compatibility by
>   reading Supporting IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Networks and watch Your App and
>   Next Generation Network

I also searched about IPv6 in Xamarin and found same error at: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/66732/does-xamarin-support-ios-ipv6-only-networks

Anyone had experience about supporting IPv6 by using Xamarin, please advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've just found the solution, library Xam.Plugin.Connectivity does not support IPv6. I removed the library and get approved!

Comment: Do you have information as to why it got reject to help me update the library?

Comment: Here is a potentially-related GitHub issue (with a nice link at the bottom on how to set up an IPv6-only network on El Capitan): https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/issues/331

Comment: I updated my Nuget tonight with some fixes for ipv6 it is now 2.2.0-beta1 to try out if you would like. I have submitted an update to the app store for testing.

Comment: So we just need to update Xam.Plugin to version 2.2.20-beta1, right?

Comment: I'm using 2.3 and still having this problem. Anyone else using a recent version and getting rejected? Any workarounds?